# Grails pagination set maximum records

Tags: grails, pagination, grails-orm

When using pagination in groovy I want to have a max of 10 per page but also I want the query to return after I hit 500 records.

So let's say with my criteria there are 10,000 records that match, I want the PagedResultList to return 10 and the results.totalCount = 500 NOT 10,000.

I've been trying to do this with maxResults(500) in the criteria but have been unsuccessful. Can you not use maxResults when also using max?

Answer (score 0):

`max` will return an ArrayList with your objects.

`maxResults` will return a `PagedResultList` of witch you can use `totalCount` to issue a second query to count the objects that match your criteria. The totalCount is a second query - it does not actually fetch all 10k objects.

So I'm not sure how to solve the issue you describe, since if the query does match 10k in your db, that will be your total count. You could possibly code in a check if totalcount is > 500, display 500.

But if your concern is GORM is pulling back 10k objects, it is not. See the first example http://docs.grails.org/3.2.10/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html for more info.

A very simple controller to show the behavior:

```
def index() {
    println "max:"
    def q1 = Foo.createCriteria().list(max: 10) { }
    println q1.class.name
    println q1.totalCount


    println "maxResults:"
    def q2 = Foo.createCriteria().list {
        maxResults(10)
    }
    println q2.class.name
    // println q2.size() // totalCount doesn't exist on an ArrayList
}
```

output:

```
max:
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, 
this_.name as name3_0_0_ from foo this_ limit ?
grails.orm.PagedResultList
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from foo this_
2 

maxResults:
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_, 
this_.name as name3_0_0_ from foo this_ limit ?
java.util.ArrayList
```

You can also see the hql generated is the same either way and a second query is sent for the totalCount.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know it's not pulling back all 10k objects but, isn't it completing the query to know there are 10k objects....isn't that how we get the totalcount?

Comment: I'm not sure what "completing the query" means, the db runs the query and gets a result. I'm not aware of a way in sql to what you describe. If your doing this on an indexed field it should be very quick.